# Does STATE LISTEN or ESTABLISHED means I should see an open port when using nmap?

Tags: kali-linux, nmap

Should ports that are in LISTENING, ESTABLISHED or not identified states appear as open ports in nmap?

Doing some search on google I've found this:

> Any "ESTABLISHED" socket means that there is a connection currently made there. Any "LISTEN" means that the socket is waiting for a connection. Both are opened ports but one is waiting for a connection to be made while the other has a connection already made.

I've used `netstat` on windows powershell to show process states:

```
netstat -nboa
Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
[svchost.exe]
TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
[svchost.exe]
TCP    0.0.0.0:7680           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       21240
[svchost.exe]
TCP    192.168.0.106:60478    155.133.255.100:27035  ESTABLISHED     21016
[msedge.exe]
UDP    0.0.0.0:60288          104.71.216.88:443                      10736
[steam.exe]
TCP    192.168.0.106:64644    52.2.219.0:443         ESTABLISHED     4456
```

Then tested using vmbox guest Kali Linux `nmap -v -p 445 192.168.0.106` for those Local Address ports. I've also tried using `-f`, `-T0` and `-T1`, but all of them returned either STATE closed or filtered.

I've also tested my guest OS IP address

```
ss -tnp
tcp  ESTAB 0 0 192.168.0.111:47658 34.117.65.55:443 users:(("firefox-esr",pid=1648,fd=106))
```

And then using `nmap -v -p 47658 192.168.0.111`, it resulted in STATE closed.

Am I doing something wrong? Should I be seeing those ports as OPEN?

Comment: Yes you should see an open port, but... firewalls would block `nmap` even if the port is listening.

Comment: netstat has been deprecates for years.  Use 'ss'.    Similarly 'ifconfig' is deprecated in facor of 'ip'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should ports that are in LISTENING, ESTABLISHED or not identified states appear as open ports in nmap?

LISTENING, yes. ESTABLISHED, no. An 'established' socket represents a connection that already exists, and is not in any way an "open port".

Note how the output doesn't actually tell you *which side* was originally listening when the connection was made – it is not necessarily an incoming connection to your machine; indeed all three connections in your output appear to be outgoing, with the ***remote*** system listening on port 443 or 27035 at the time those connections were established. The local port of those sockets never had a listening socket at all.

The one "Not identified" socket in your list isn't even TCP – it's UDP. (UDP does not have any connection states.) Nmap can scan UDP ports but you need to explicitly tell it to do so. However, again, judging by the port numbers it is an outbound stream – the remote system is listening on UDP port 443, while the local port is just temporarily assigned to that single stream.

Comment: Your terminology needs work. A connected Tcp port is certainly OPEN in a very meaningful sense.  However nmap defines open as 'An application is actively accepting TCP connections, UDP datagrams or SCTP associations on this port'.   So an open tcp connection is not "open" to nmap.

Comment: @stevea: That's the OP's terminology, not mine. Connections are not ports, though, and Nmap does not scan connections, it scans ports. "Open connection" and "open port" do not mean the same thing, do they?

Comment: a TCP connection involves a pair of ports and certain state on each end. I validly described a "connected port" (a port involved in a connected TCP state), I did not claim that a connection was a port.  The user referred to nmap - which has a documented and peculiar definition of "open".   NO - you were't re-iterating the OP nor nmap when you claimed "not in any way".  That's an expansive and erroneous claim.